# save values from html table to database

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have a html table that displays values from the database. I have a javascript that enables me to edit this data but then i cant figure out how to save it back to the database using php. i found some information that i should use xmlhttprequests but i have no idea on how to do this. Any suggestions? Your help is highly appreciated. Code below;

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--

    function edit_input(obj) {
    var is_checked = obj.checked;
    while (obj.tagName!='TR')
    obj = obj.parentNode;

    var td = obj.getElementsByTagName('TD');
    var len = td.length;

    if (!is_checked) {

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
    if (td[i].className=='editable')
    td[i].innerHTML = td[i].firstChild.value;


    } else {

    var input;

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
    if (td[i].className=='editable') {
    input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    input.value = td[i].innerHTML;
    td[i].innerHTML = '';
    td[i].appendChild(input);
    }
    }

    }


    --></script>


    </head>

    <body>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
         <th width="56">Branch ID</th>
    <th width="75">Branch Name</th>
         <th width="75">Branch Personnel</th>                            
         <th width="105">Branch Headquaters</th>
    <th width="50">Edit</th>
    </tr>
<?php

$result = mysql_query($query );
    while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
         <tr>
             <td class="editable"><?php echo $row['branchid'];?></td>
             <td class="editable"><?php echo $row['branchname'];?></td>     
             <td class="editable"><?php echo $row['branchpersonnel'];?></td>
             <td class="editable"><?php echo $row['branchhq'];?></td>   
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="edit_inpu(this);">Edit</td>  
         </tr>                                          
<?php } ?>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="editbranch" class="button2"       value="Update"/></td></tr> 
</table>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to learn AJAX see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: http://w3fools.com/ ... maybe have a look there once you've looked at w3schools

Comment: @RupeshPawar - You should probably avoid recommending w3schools. It has some serious problems.

Comment: AJAX on Mozilla Developer Network (MDN):  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX

Comment: thanx for the idea, but is there a way of doing this without including ajax? maybe just using php and javascript?

Comment: AJAX is JavaScript. But you could also create a form and send all `input` values.

Comment: @AaronLee You just opened my eyes. Thank you!

Comment: haha, no worries, but in regards to the question there are probably others means of going about doing it but AJAX is your best chance.

Answer (score 2):

If using jQuery is not a problem, maybe using something like [JEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) is a solution. When you click on a cell in a table, it turns into a textfield, and when pressing enter or leaving focus, it makes a webrequest to the server, where you can make the changes.

See for example [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mb9Rn/) jsfiddle script. It's really easy to use. The only other thing you would need to do is to give the table cells an id, which gets sent to the page you are saving it too.

Comment: Hi Ikke, thank but as simple as using jquery is i have not used it before. i know i should learn it, and i will but i cant apply it now. any other ideas?

Comment: Learning jQuery is easier than learning javascript and XHR. This component handles all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have your script fire off an Ajax request through [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to a PHP script that saves the values back to the database.

The URL could be something like this: `updatetable.php?row=0&col=0&data=1234`

Comment: am trying to understand you but somehow am lost. so i should have a separate php script that does the update then address my update button as updatetable.php?row=0&col=0&data=1234
? what does this mean?

Comment: No, you should use Ajax to fire off a HTTP request to the script. See the XMLHttpRequest documentation I linked.

Comment: i get it now but could you please explain the url part more?how can i customize the url to get the data from the table and post it to the update.php page?

Comment: You could serialize the table data into a JSON string and send it as a POST parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery, is very popular.

you have to download the lib and include-it on the header

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js

and here it's how you use a ajax request with jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The url param is your location to send the values to save them like the post.